# Getting error Effect "n.loadInfo$" dispatched an invalid action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to write an effect for an action but it is throwing an error as:
*"**Effect "n.loadInfo$" dispatched an invalid action: null Error**"*

I have my effect as below:

```
  @Effect()
  loadInfo$ = 
        this.actions.ofType(fromHeaderActions.EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromSelectors.GetINFOPayload)),
    switchMap(([action, infoPayLoad]) => {
      let cAction: fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdget = 
          <fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdget>action;
      return this.infoService.loadINFO(infoPayLoad).pipe(
       // Dispatch success action
          map(response => new 
              fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdgetSuccess(response)),
      catchError(error => {
        return of(new 
         fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdgetFail(error.message))
      })
     )
   })
 );
```

I have my action defined as below:

```
export class OpenINFOWIdget extends BaseGetDetailsAction implements Action {
  readonly type = EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO; 
  constructor() {
  super();   
 }
}


//added action after the comment
export class OpenINFOWIdgetSuccess extends BaseGetDetailsAction 
 implements Action {
 readonly type = EInfoHeaderActions.OPEN_INFO_SUCCESS;
 constructor(public payload: INFO) {
  super();
  }
 }

export class OpenINFOWIdget extends BaseGetDetailsAction implements Action {
  readonly type = EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO_FAIL;
  constructor(public payload: string) {
  super();    
 }
}
```

And in the service as below:

```
public INFOPayloadsource = new BehaviorSubject<INFO>(initINFO);
infoPayload$ = this.INFOPayloadsource.asObservable();

private SelectedInfoSource = new Subject<INFO>();
selectedInfo$ = this.SelectedInfoSource.asObservable();

  loadINFO(payload: INFO): Observable<INFO> {    
   if (payload != null) {
     this.IsInfoEnableSource.next(true);     
     this.InfoPayloadsource.next(payload);
   }
   return this.selectedInfo$;
  }
```

I have selector as below that is used in the effect:

```
export const GetINFOPayload = createSelector(getInfoState, 
(state: 
      InfoDetailsState) => {
        if (state) {
          if (state.infoDetails != null && 
              state.infoDetails.INFODetail != 
              null &&
              state.infoDetails.INFODetail.Active != null) {
           let payload: INFO = { ...initINFO };
           payload = state.infoDetails.INFODetail.Active;
           return payload;
        }
      }
    return null;
  });
```

Create reducer as below after the comment:

```
case 
  fromInfoDetailsHeaderActions.EInfoHeaderActions.OPEN_INFO: {
      return {
        ...state,
        IsScreenOverlay: true,
        IsEditable: false
      }
    };
    case fromInfoDetailsHeaderActions.EInfoHeaderActions.OPEN_INFO_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        IsScreenOverlay: false,
        IsEditable: true
      }
    };
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effect is trying to dispatch the result of `this.infoService.loadINFO()`, which is why you get the error saying that it is not a valid action.

You should `map` this to a success action instead:

```js
  @Effect()
  loadInfo$ = this.actions.ofType(fromHeaderActions.EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromSelectors.GetINFOPayload)
    ),
    switchMap(([action, infoPayLoad]) => {
      let cAction: fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdget = <fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdget>action;

      return this.infoService.loadINFO(infoPayLoad).pipe(
        // Dispatch success action
        map(response => new fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdgetSuccess(response)),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(new fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdgetFail(error.message))
        })
       )
     })
 );
```

You will also need to add the corresponding action and handle it in your reducer, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Steve, I will check and let you know once it is working.

Comment: the effect is not triggering the success reducer (OPEN_INFO_SUCCESS) that I created if you would please advise if I am missing anything.  I updated the description as per your suggestion. @Steve

Comment: If anyone can assist on above comments. Thank you!

Comment: @CodeVenture did you get this working in the end? ...or is the reducer still not running?

Comment: Oh, I can see your service is returning an observable. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. I resolved it by returning return of(this.selectedInfo$). Just want to confirm if it is correct @Steve? Thank you!